# What is an entropy of a random seed and how it works?

Tags: random, random-seed

Inspired by a question asked in SO about randomness vs uniqueness, I did some research on general RNGs and methods employed in them. The entropy of a seed was mentioned in most of the articles I skimmed through.

What is an entropy of a seed and what is the concept behind it for a quick grasp?

Comment: It's really a measure of the process that produced the seed rather than the seed itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, for random number generation purposes, a seed's entropy means how hard the seed is to predict, expressed as a number of bits.  For example, if a 64-bit seed has 32 bits of entropy, it is as hard to predict as a 32-bit data block chosen randomly.

Entropy is more often spoken of in terms of [*noise sources*](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Nondeterministic_Sources_and_Seed_Generation) with chaotic behavior.  In general, the more chaotic the behavior, the more entropy the noise source has.  Examples include—

- timings of keystrokes and input devices,
- atmospheric noise, and
- the noise registered by the low-order bits of recorded audio and video outputs.

A seed's entropy is then based on the entropy of the noise sources that the seed is derived from.  However, it's anything but trivial to find a noise source's entropy at any given time.